# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException with null arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My code works when tested with an `ArrayList` that contain objects but puts out the following error when the `arrayList` is empty:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

What am I getting wrong?

Gets the `Rectangle` with the smallest area
 return the rectangle with the smallest area or `null` if
 there are no rectangles.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RectangleList 
{

    ArrayList<Rectangle> list = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    public RectangleList(ArrayList<Rectangle> theList) 
    {
        list = theList;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Rectangle with the smallest area
     * 
     * @return the rectangle with the smallest area or null if there are no
     *         rectangles
     * 
     */
    public Rectangle smallestArea() 
    {

        Rectangle currentsmallestRectangle = list.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            Rectangle nextRectangle = list.get(i);

            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else if ((nextRectangle.getWidth() * nextRectangle.getHeight()) < (currentsmallestRectangle
                    .getWidth() * currentsmallestRectangle.getHeight())) {
                currentsmallestRectangle = nextRectangle;

            }

            return currentsmallestRectangle;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If your `List` is empty, you can't access the element at index 0.

Comment: Detect if you have an empty `ArrayList` with the `size()` method; you'll have to handle that condition somehow: return `null`, or throw an `Exception`, or...

Comment: And for future reference, including the line number (and highlighting exactly which line) where the exception is being thrown is incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 5):

> Hi my code works when tested with ArrayLists that contain objects but puts out the error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 when the arrayList is empty. What am I getting wrong.

`ArrayList.get()` is behaving exactly [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29).

> **Throws:**
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (`index < 0 || index >= size()`)

There are no entries, so index 0 is out of bounds. If you want to return `null` if there are no rectangles, you should do that explicitly:

```
// Alternatively, if list.size() == 0
if (list.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
}
```

Note that a reference to an empty list is very different from a null reference, by the way. (Your title refers to a "null arrayList" - there's no such thing as a null object, but there can be a null reference... except there isn't in your case.)

This needs to be done *before* you otherwise call `list.get(0)` - and only once. (What's the point of calling it in the loop?) For example:

```
public Rectangle smallestArea() {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    Rectangle currentsmallestRectangle = list.get(0);
    // Note that you can go from 1, not 0...
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Rectangle nextRectangle = list.get(i);
        if ((nextRectangle.getWidth() * nextRectangle.getHeight()) <
            (currentsmallestRectangle.getWidth() * 
             currentsmallestRectangle.getHeight())) {
            currentsmallestRectangle = nextRectangle;
        }
    }
    return currentSmallestRectangle;
}
```

Ideally, add an `area()` method to your `Rectangle` class, to make the loop simpler:

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Rectangle nextRectangle = list.get(i);
    if (nextRectangle.area() < currentSmallestRectangle.area()) {
        currentsmallestRectangle = nextRectangle;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to return null explicitly previously just as you indicated and it didnt work.

Comment: @user2868810: It should work absolutely fine. If you need us to help you work out what went wrong, you need to tell us what happened. "It didn't work" isn't *nearly* enough information.

Comment: Sorry about that.the code is supposed to return the Rectangle with the smallest area in an ArrayList list of Rectangles and output null if the ArrayList is empty. I have modified the code wit the If condition you put up but the same IndexOutOfBound exception error persists.

Comment: @user2868810 You're still accessing the list before checking if it's empty! You should check the if the list is empty before doing any `list.get()`.

Comment: @user2868810: As Marc-Andre says, you should have that code at the *start* of the method. I'll edit my answer to show that. You should also make sure you actually understand the code in question - you should have been able to work this out for yourself.

Comment: @Jon and Marc thanks a lot for your help and patience. I have just started to use java for two weeks now, and its also my first time on this forum  pardon the errors. However I have learnt some useful guidelines with respect to my post so I will adopt that in the future and I have definitely gained a better understanding of Java from this interaction. Thanks you guys for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to get element zero from an empty list. You can't do that.

Comment: Could you make a suggestion how to deal with that, I have tried many options even the ones proffered here and they seem not to work

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
   try
   {
         Rectangle currentsmallestRectangle = list.get(0);
   }
   catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
   {
        return 0;//Do something here to fix exception
   }
```

or

```
   if(!list.isEmpty())
   {
         Rectangle currentsmallestRectangle = list.get(0);
   }
   else
   {
        return 0;//Put something here as default. maybe a rectangle size 0.
   }
```

You don't check if list has anything in it so there are problems if you don't take care of it. The two pieces of code above can correct it and they will return 0 to say there are no rectangles.